# How to move the Laravel timestamps column to a special location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I want to move timestamps columns to a specific location. Let's pretend I already have an app running on a production server with the following schema:
**ORDERS**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

So after a few days, I added the following columns:

```
  $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained('user_addresses');
            $table->string('payment_method')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_status')->default('pending');
            $table->string('order_status')->default('in_cart');
            $table->text('note')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('total', 8, 2)->default(0);
            $table->string('waybill')->nullable();
            $table->string('logistic')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('payment_at')->nullable();
```

The problem here is that all these columns are added after timestamps, but I don't want to add them after timestamps. I want to add them between id and timestamps. Also, I don't want to lose already created timestamps.

Comment: Do you mean the columns appear after the `timestamp` columns (`created_at` etc.) but you want them to appear before them?

Comment: You may use `after()` in every column or may use like this.[Column Order](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-order)

Comment: @Peppermintology yes but i don't want to loose timestamps data.

Comment: Which major version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Peppermintology laravel 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`after()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers) column modifier to add columns after (obviously) another column. However, as of Laravel 8.27 you can group columns making life a little simpler:

```
Schema::table('orders', function ($table) {
    $table->after('name', function ($table) {
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained('user_addresses');
        $table->string('payment_method')->nullable();
        $table->string('payment_status')->default('pending');
        $table->string('order_status')->default('in_cart');
        $table->text('note')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('total', 8, 2)->default(0);
        $table->string('waybill')->nullable();
        $table->string('logistic')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('payment_at')->nullable();
    });
});
```

That should place all columns defined inside the `after` method after the `name` column but before the `timestamps` columns.

Comment: @HimanshuRahi No worries, pleased it's solved.  [:

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [custom order](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-order) for solve this issue

```
$table->after('name', function ($table) {
      $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
      $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained('user_addresses');
      $table->string('payment_method')->nullable();
      $table->string('payment_status')->default('pending');
      $table->string('order_status')->default('in_cart');
      $table->text('note')->nullable();
      $table->decimal('total', 8, 2)->default(0);
      $table->string('waybill')->nullable();
      $table->string('logistic')->nullable();
      $table->dateTime('payment_at')->nullable();
});
```

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers) have `->after('column')` column modifier. Place the column "after" another column (MySQL).
Hope it's work for you